# Using PHP strings as element ID in HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays

I’m trying to dynamically create `<p>` elementss with different ids to "fill" them with JavaScript’s `innerHTML` property.

Firstly I try to create 50 times:

```
echo "<p id=space1></p>";
```

But the number up going like space2, space3 etc.

I made this loop to generate the incrementing numbers and put it together with the string, and echo it:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 50; $x++) {
   $xarray = array($x => "space" . $x);
   echo "<p id=$xarrray[$x]></p>";
}
```

But when I run it and check the HTML code on the page, all I see is:

```
<p id=""></p>
```

But when I check the arrays by directly echoing them, the names get displayed correctly.

So how can I use my php strings as element ID in HTML?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a typo in retrieving your array.

```
$xarray = array($x => "space" . $x);
echo "<p id=$xarrray[$x]></p>";
```

Your first line it's called $xarray and your second line it's called $xarrray (extra r)

```
$xarray=array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= 50; $x++) {
    $xarray[$x] = "space" . $x;
    echo '<p id="{$xarray[$x]}"></p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally oversaw that :/
After removing this typo it works exactly the way i tried it in the question.

Comment: It happens :)  If you plan on using the array you should initiate it outside the loop to stop anything unexpected from happening. Also  don't forget to wrap your p id in either single or double quotes

Comment: @Snoeny you may want to look at using an IDE - many will warn you about undefined variables, etc. even though PHP is very loose with declaration vs use much less data type etc

Answer (score -1):

```
<p id="<?php echo $php_variable; ?>"></p>
```

This is because the server runs and compile before the browser renders the view/template. On rendering the above P element in your DOM, $php_variable would have been resolved and echoed into the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
   $xarray=array();
   for ($x = 1; $x <= 50; $x++) 
   {
        $xarray[$x] = "space" . $x;
        echo "<p id='" . $xarray[$x] . "'></p>";
   }
```

Comment: tried it and still just get this as html code: <p id=""></p>

Comment: @Snoeny there was a typo, sorry, try again now :)